# Grails 3.2 - List field names in domain class that are not nullable

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I get a list of field names for a domain class that are not nullable?

For instance, in the following domain:

```
class MyDomain {
    String field1
    String field2
    String field3
    String field4

    static constraints = {
        field2 nullable: true
        field3 nullable: true
    }
}
```

How can I get back the list `['field1','field4']` in a controller?

I'm validating rows in a CSV, and some of the row information is different from what is stored in the domain, so it would be preferable to get a List of String names rather than bind to a command object with exclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `constrainedProperties`. It gives all the constraints of the particular domain class.

And now you want only the non-nullble constraints then filter out the result for it.

Example :

```
MyDomain.constrainedProperties.findResults { it.value.nullable ? null : it.key }
```

Output :

```
['field1','field4']
```

> For grails 2.x users :

`MyDomain.getConstraints().findResults { it.value.nullable ? null : it.key` }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PersistentEntity API

```
Set<String> propertyNames = [] as Set
for (PersistentProperty prop: MyDomain.gormPersistentEntity.persistentProperties) {
    if (!prop.mapping.mappedForm.nullable) {
        propertyNames.add(prop.name)
    }     
}
```

You may have to exclude things like version or timestamp properties depending on what you want.